# Unique SAT vs Exactly $m$ models

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, reference-request, np-hardness, sat, reductions

Unique SAT is the well known problem : given a CNF formula $F$, is it true that $F$ has exactly one model ?

I am interested in « Exactly $m$-SAT » problem : given a CNF formula $F$ and an integer $m>1$, is it true that $F$ has exactly $m$ models ?

Both problems look similar. So my questions are :

1- Is «Exactly $m$-SAT » polytime (many-one or Turing) reducible to Unique SAT?

2- Do you know any reference on the subject ?

Thank you for your answers.

**Addendum**, first articles about complexity of Exactly $m$ SAT :

1- Janos Simon, On the Difference Between One and Many, In Proceedings of the Fourth Colloquium on Automata, Languages and Programming, 480-491, 1977.

2- Klaus W. Wagner, The complexity of combinatorial problems with succinct input representation, Acta Informatica, 23, 325-356, 1986.

In both articles, Exactly $m$ SAT ($m \geq 1$) is shown to be $C=$ complete (under many-one reductions), where the class $C$ is from the Counting Hierarchy (CH) of complexity classes. Informally, $C$ contains all problems which can be expressed as deciding whether a given
instance has at least $m$ many polynomial size proofs (the class $C$ is known to coincide with the class $PP$). The class $C=$ is a variant of $C$, where “exactly $m$” replaces “at least $m$".

Comment: It is polytime Turing reducible: find a solution, add a clause eliminating it, and repeat till the formula becomes unsatisfiable.

Comment: @Kaveh ,Tks. 1- what if the initial formula hasn't exactly m models ? (possibly exactly one); 2- how to be sure that the added clause eliminates no more than one solution ? (then we would have to test the values of m'<m)

Comment: 1. the machine will tell the number of solutions or that it has more than $m$ solutions. 2. you can add the negation of conjunction describing the solution.

Comment: @Kaveh, 1. I meant what if the machine gives a no answer to the Exactly $m$ SAT problem ?  (we don't have access to the number of solutions, $m$ is given) 2. Nice !

Comment: (I should cut and paste this :)): answers, not comments...

Comment: @Kaveh: I do not think that your reduction works unless m is polynomially bounded in the input size.

Comment: @Kaveh: I realized that I cannot understand your reduction even for m=2.  How can you use the oracle for Unique SAT to find a solution for a SAT instance with two answers?  Are you using the randomized reduction by Valiant and Vazirani?

Comment: @Tsuyoshi, you are right, I misunderstood the question.

Comment: @Xavier: I cannot see how to solve “Exactly m SAT” by using the NP oracle twice.  Care to elaborate?

Comment: @Tsuyoshi: It is the same kind of oracle calls for US and "Exactly $m$ models" :  First NP call : Has the formula more or equal $m$ models ? Second co-NP call : Has the formula stricly less than $m+1$ models ?

Comment: What if m is exponentially large in the input size?  I think that you are using the PP oracle twice.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi: 1- Why is it necessary to introduce probalistic TM even if $m$ is exponentially large in the input size ? 2- Let $m$ be small enough, the question of reducibility from "Exactly $m$ SAT" to US remains.

Comment: If you do not know the relation between PP and counting the number of solutions, please check a textbook on complexity theory such as Papadimitriou.

Comment: Also, please make an effort to state your question precisely, and update the question so that people can understand your question without reading comments.

Comment: Well, if you think that your questions are too naive, I have to agree.  Honestly speaking, I think that you should have asked your questions on math.stackexchange.com instead of cstheory.stackexchange.com.  They are by no means research-level questions in complexity theory.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi : Tks for the link (naive questions do have virtues, I learnt this from my students).

Comment: @Tayfun,about your comment :-) - What else do you think about the posted question ?

Comment: (1) If m is polynomially bounded, your problem is polynomial-time many-one reducible to Unique SAT by treating a list of m solutions sorted in the lexicographical order as a single certificate.  (2) Please do not take my giving an answer as an evidence that you asked your question in the right place.  I think that this particular question is on the border line between on-topic and off-topic.  You should really consider asking your future questions somewhere else.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi : (1) This reduction maps yes instances, what about no instances ? (2) tks for your concern.

Comment: It maps no-instances to no-instances (otherwise I would not call it a reduction).

Comment: @Tsuyoshi : Please make your answering comment a full answer.

Comment: Although you state that m is polynomially bounded, some of the statements in the question require m to be arbitrary and no longer hold if you constrain m to be polynomially bounded.  You have to understand what you are talking about before you can ask a coherent question.  This is why I do not want to post an answer to this question here, where questions are expected to be at research level.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For general $m$, exactly-m-sat is strictly harder than u-sat (thus does not reduce to it) unless the PH collapses.  The reason is that PP can be obtained using an existential quantifier over exactly-m-SAT queries (exists m>(half of the assignments) such that exactly-m-SAT), thus if exactly-m-sat is in the k'th level of PH, then PP is in the (k+1)'st level, and then the hierarchy collapses (since P^PP contains PH).  But u-sat is clearly in the second level of PH (actually in a subclass called DP).

On the other hand, as @Tsuyoshi mentioned above, if $m$ is polynomial, then exactly-m-sat is many-one reudcible to u-sat.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 1) If $m$ is small enough (ie polynomially bounded in $n$, the size of the formula) then Exactly $m$ SAT is reducible to US. Besides, if $m$, as part of the input, is big enough (ie $m= 2^{O(n)}$) then Exactly $m$ SAT is in P. Why would it be such a drastic change for $m$ in between ? 2) What do you think of the update post ? (why is it not correct ?)

Comment: Large m still don't put the problem in P.  The update post is incorrect since the statement that exactly-k-sat is C=P-complete is true when k is part of the input, and thus your reduction to k/2-sat does not make sense.

Comment: $m$ is part of the input. Let introduce $m$ new variables, $y_1,y_2 \cdots y_m $. Let $F'=F\land y_1 \land y_2 \land \cdots \land y_m $. $F'$ has exactly the same number of models as $F$, and $m$ is polynomially bound in the size of $F'$. Why not conclude that the reduction to US (via $F'$) holds ?

Comment: $F'$ is exponential in size of $F$ (if $m$ is exponential in $|F|$), thus the reduction is not poly-time in general.